# Can I make os-level keyboard bindings in racket?

Tags: racket

Using xbindkeys I can register key bindings to run a command or run a guile scheme function. For example windows key + Up to maximize screen

Does racket have any libraries that could be used to register global key combination bindings, that could trigger racket functions? I would much rather write scripts in racket than in guile scheme.

Python also has something similar here
https://python-evdev.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage.html#listing-accessible-event-devices

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not clear exactly what you're asking, but it looks to me like you're hoping to replace the guile backend used in xbindkeys's configuration file with Racket. There might be an easier way to do this, but I think I would suggest that unless you have a need for specific features, this might be a great time to get to know Guile better :).

Comment: I'm using xbindkeys but wished there was something cross platform in racket so I can macro my quick keys. Guile is rot.